# Using a Bluetooth USB Device on 2012 Hyper-V Host or VM

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, bluetooth, windows-server-2012

i need to be able to use a USB bluetooth stick on either a Windows Server 2012 R2 Host OR on one of its virtual machines. The VM could be a WS2012 as well or a Windows 7 OS.

I have 2 problems
- Windows server does not provide a bluetooth stack
- How to use a USB device that is not recognized by the host on a windows 7 VM?

Maybe there is a way in Virtual Box i dont know about, but i would need to be able to install drivers on the host first, right?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get bluetooth to work on Windows Server 2012?](http://superuser.com/questions/504162/how-can-i-get-bluetooth-to-work-on-windows-server-2012)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work 100%, thats why i'd like to use the device on an w7 VM. But how to get ist mounted there?